# Offset().top not returning the value on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am working of a web application that having more than one iframes and needs to be fix the height dynamically for the various screen.

I tried to assign the height of a iframe inside the page using the following code,

```
var y = $('#ordersfavld2').offset().top;
var z = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var d = (z - (y + 5));
$('#ordersfavld2').css({ 'height': d, 'overflow-y': 'auto' });
```

This code is working and returns some 'px' value when reloading the iframe, but returns '0px' when loading the page.

[image]

I have attached the screenshot for your easy understanding.

```
<div id="tab_3" class="tab-pane" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
  <iframe src="" width="100%" id="Iframe4" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

and the page content inside the iframe is,

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="ordersfavld2">
<div class="portlet light bordered orders_right_portlet" id="OrdersHgt">
    <div class="portlet-body" id="OrdersHgt2">
        <div class="portlet-body" id="divlab">
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped" id="orders_tbl">
                    <thead id="orderdisplay">
                        <tr align="center">
                            <th class="bluetxt" colspan="7" >
                                <b>ORDERS</b>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="labdisp">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="portlet box green ext_ordr_port" id="Exsearchdisplay">
    <div class="portlet-title" id="labtitle">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 caption">
            <i class="fa fa-list"></i> EXISTING ORDERS
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 radio_clm">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="RdoInves" id="RdoInvesALL" checked onclick="fnRadioClick()" />ALL</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="RdoInves" id="RdoLastOne" onclick="fnRadioClick()" />Last One Day</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="RdoInves" id="RdoLastSeven" onclick="fnRadioClick()" />Last Seven Days</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="RdoInves" id="RdoAganistvisit" onclick="fnRadioClick()" />Against Visit</label>
                        &nbsp;
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="fullscreen2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="" title="Expand" ><i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-body">
        <div class="table-container">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="labtable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Order No</th>
                        <th>Order Date</th>
                        <th>Doctor</th>
                        <th>Existing Orders</th>
                        <th>Clinical Detail & Presumptive Diagnosis</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                        <th>Print</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using iframe, it has to load a HTML inside your HTML. By the time it load the iframe, your script might run and returns the value as Zero.

So call you function inside winodow.load

Thanks !

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But here $('#ordersfavld2') is the div inside the iframe and needs to dynamically set the height and gives the scroll. 

So placing the code inside $(window).load will not gives me expected result.

Comment: Could you show me the HTML strcuture.?
i belive we cant access any elemets which is inside the iframe.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set height for your `iframe` and let the `iframe`'s content have it's height determined by it's content?

```
<div id="tab_3" class="tab-pane" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
    <iframe src="" width="100%" height="400" id="Iframe4" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

This way your `iframe` will have a set height with only one scrollbar for the `iframe`'s content instead of - possibly - two.

Comment: The iframe height had set dynamically and contents of each tabs are  different html pages that are loaded inside each iframe of corresponding tabs.

Comment: Here's what I'm thinking - If you're using tabs for different iframes, I'm sure you'll want to have consistency in how it looks. Unless each iframe is displayed one below the other, setting iframe's height dynamically won't do much help.